# VB6, WScript.Shell: runas doesn't recognize password when sent using SendKeys

Tags: vb6, wsh

I have an application which needs to run with elevated permissions. I'm creating a WScript.Shell object, calling "runas" with an administrator user name, and then sending the password using SendKeys.

For some strange reason, this doesn't work, and I'm getting an "unknown username or password" message. The password is definitely the correct one. When I tried starting the window from the application but entering the password manually - everything works.

Here is the code:

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal milliseconds As Long)

Private Function RunExecutableAs(executableName As String, userName As String, password As String) As Boolean
    Dim shell       As Object
    Dim result      As Long

    Set shell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
    result = shell.run("C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k runas /user:""" + userName + """ """ + executableName + """", 2, False)

    If result = 0
        Sleep 1000
        shell.SendKeys password + "{ENTER}"
        Set shell = Nothing
        RunExecutableAs = True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: [This](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/285879) uses `CreateProcessWithLogon`

Comment: SendKeys isn't going to work.  The dialog should appear on the secure desktop, which it can't reach.  This who concept is shifty anyway, the UAC dialog is meant to be handled by a real person.